# 3ds importer porting for Blender 2.80 is done?

Tags: add-on, import

I've been spying hard on when 3ds import/ export functionality will be ported to Blender 2.8/ 2.9.
Looks like it's done or at least in advanced development stage and it's already usable.

Please see there:
https://developer.blender.org/T66329

There is a DIFF file shared and I don't know how to use it. It's not a fully usable add-on itself, right? How can it be turned into a usable script that I can install in Blender 2.8?

I completely don't understand devs' discussions. I'm just a beginner user, so I don't even dare to post anything on DEV forum. Just want to know if the data they shared on the linked page can already be used as a functional importing add-on.

Comment: Did you try it yet? You can help the developers by trying it and reporting errors if you find them.

Comment: No, because I don't know how to use it. For the first time I saw something like DIFF file. I googled the definition but still don't know how to do it.

Comment: There is also export_3ds.py file. Maybe that's the compiled add-on? I installed it for Blender 2.90, got a message looking like a successful installation, but I cannot see the add-on on the list in Prefs. Perhaps I should install Blender 2.8, because the add-on is not compatible with 2.90? Or maybe I shoud use the DIFF file, but how? So many questions, so little answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3DS import and export will be available again in Blender version 3.6 as stated in the [Blender 3.6 Release Notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.6/Add-ons)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found out that the addon is already shipped with 2.92 alpha, so I downloaded the freshest build and copied the addon to my 2.90 addons folder.
It works flawlessly ^^